# c3.js making step function chart with confidence intervals as areas

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I'd like to make a step line chart but with the ability to create confidence intervals that are filled in.

A good example would be in this link: http://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/6552457

My thought was to modify an area chart to customize where the area would be filled. However, I don't see any documentation on it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: make a "Combination Chart" containing "Stacked Area Charts" and "Step Chart", make the fill of the bottom area `transparent`

Comment: How would this work in the lower confidence interval case?